# Capitalizing variable name in C program using regular expressions

Tags: regex

I need to find a variable in a C program and need to convert its 1st letter to upper case. For example:

```
int sum;
sum = 50;
```

I need to find `sum` and I should convert it to `Sum`. How can I achieve this using regular expressions (find and replace)?

Comment: Is this just about the sum variable or any type of variable?

Comment: That conversion can result in incorrect or invalid programs. What if you already have a variable with the same name? There are many other creative edge cases I can think of...

Comment: i need to change all variables in my program like this way..

Answer (score 3):

This can't be done with a regex. You need a C language parser for that, otherwise how would you know what is a variable, what is a keyword, what is a function name, what is a word inside a string or a comment...

Comment: Agreed, but not sure about if it's impossible or not, C is not that hard to parse ;)

Comment: @Qtax, in this particular case I guess I would use search and replace using my eyes as the parser :)

Comment: @Qtax, it is not possible *theoretically* to accomplish this task using regexes, just because the C language cannot be described using regular grammar.

Comment: @Igor, who said anything about PCRE being regular? This is not formal language theory, regex here refers to modern implementations like PCRE/Perl/etc, which are not regular.

Comment: @Qtax, OP explicitly said "*regular* expressions" :) Anyway, even with PCRE/Perl/Java/etc. regexes this will be a nightmare, but you're right, a possible nigthmare :)

Comment: @Igor, ah, you are right, OP never said regex. ;) (But a challenge can be fun now and then ;))

Answer (score 0):

.Net's Regex replace support what you want to do (if you can come up with the regular expression you need).  The ReplaceCC function at the bottom is invoked to provide the replacement value.
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
          string sInput, sRegex;

```
      // The string to search.
      sInput = @"int sum;
sum = 1;";

      // A very simple regular expression.
      sRegex = "sum";

      Regex r = new Regex(sRegex);

      MyClass c = new MyClass();

      // Assign the replace method to the MatchEvaluator delegate.
      MatchEvaluator myEvaluator = new MatchEvaluator(c.ReplaceCC);

      // Write out the original string.
      Console.WriteLine(sInput);

      // Replace matched characters using the delegate method.
      sInput = r.Replace(sInput, myEvaluator);

      // Write out the modified string.
      Console.WriteLine(sInput);
   }

   public string ReplaceCC(Match m)
   {
      return m.Value[0].ToUpper () + m.Value.Substring (1);     
   }
```